# HiddenSidesPane fxml example

Tags: javafx

Can Anybody tell me how to construct HiddenSidesPane in FXML not in the controller?

I am having the basic controller code for this but I am not able to understand how to create fxml structure from that.

Can I have something like this? Below code;

```
<HiddenSidesPane prefWidth="800.0" pinnedSide="TOP">
            <content>
                <HBox fillHeight="false" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT"
                    prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="800.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"
                    AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                    AnchorPane.topAnchor="3.0" StackPane.alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
                    <children>
                        <Label prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="94.0" text="Value Date From">
                            <HBox.margin>
                                <Insets right="2.0" top="5.0" />
                            </HBox.margin>
                        </Label>
                    </children>
                    <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets top="2.0" />
                    </StackPane.margin>
                </HBox>
            </content>
        </HiddenSidesPane>
```

Comment: So you want to create the HiddenSidesPane in the Scene Builder?

Comment: can I add structure in the fxml (like in the question) file if I dont want to add that from the scenebuilder? FXML code addded in the question please check.

Comment: Do you want to create a side pane which will hide/show on button click or mouse hover ,etc or you want to use particularly this 'http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/HiddenSidesPane.html'  ?

Comment: @Sarfaraz Your are speaking from the same thing. Dirk Lemmermann wrote the control and pushed it to controlsfx, like he explained here: https://dlemmermann.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/something-to-hide-you-need-hiddensidespane/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This how I made a fast example with the offical FXSampler of ControlsFX in mind:

### Assumptions

You already set up your FXML Project and added the ControlsFX.jar as dependency on your build path.

#### FXMLDocument.fxml

Watch for the import statements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.*?>


<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320"  fx:controller="javafxapplication17.FXMLDocumentController">
  <children>
    <HiddenSidesPane fx:id="pane">
      <content>
        <Label alignment="CENTER"  style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black;" maxHeight="1000.0" maxWidth="1000.0"  text="Content Node" />
      </content>
      <top>
        <Label fx:id="pinLabel"  style="-fx-background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.25);"  text="(Click to pin / unpin)" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0"  onMouseClicked="#handleMouseClicked"  />
      </top>
    </HiddenSidesPane>
  </children>
</StackPane>
```

#### FXMLController.java

Inject your variables pane and pinLabel to set them.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import org.controlsfx.control.HiddenSidesPane;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

  @FXML
  private HiddenSidesPane pane;

  @FXML
  private Label pinLabel;

  @FXML
  private void handleMouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    if (pane.getPinnedSide() != null) {
      pinLabel.setText("(unpinned)");
      pane.setPinnedSide(null);
    } else {
      pinLabel.setText("(pinned)");
      pane.setPinnedSide(Side.TOP);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
  }

}
```

#### JavaFXApplication17.java

Sorry for that name :-)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication17 extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

As far as you already know here is the JavaDoc of HiddenSidesPane: http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/HiddenSidesPane.html

And if you need an example download the Zip http://fxexperience.com/downloads/controlsfx-8.40.9.zip and unzip it, there is a file controlsfx-samples-8.40.9.jar inside. Double click it and show the sources.

Comment: No words --- Just appriciate your work. Thank you bro.

Comment: I am having one question here. How HiddenSidesPane push other content ? Means if I am having HiddenSidesPane adjacent to hbox and when Pane appears hbox should shift right side or shrink when it disappear.

Comment: Hm, as I understand HiddenSidesPane, it works only like an overlay and does not shift it's content.

Comment: Yes that I can understand. Thnq.